# Guard has problems with gem versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I ma following [railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org) and I am trying to make Guard work. I have a problem when I try to run any tests from guard console:

```
15:10:04 - INFO - Run all
15:10:04 - INFO - Running: all tests
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I have json in version 1.8.1:

```
$ gem list | grep json
json (1.8.1)
multi_json (1.10.1)
```

I updated rubygems to version 2.4.2 nad ran `gem pristine --all` but id does not change anything, even the warning still exists.

I tried killing spring, restarting everything, etc - no help.

Comment: Is the gem in your `Gemfile`? And did you run a `bundle install` or `bundle update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I resolved this. I deleted all `json` entries in `Gemfile.lock`. Then I ran `bundle install` and it works!